# OpenGL specular highlights drawing add high angled view

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I try to render a big block of individual cubes in OpenGL and i'm now experimenting with lighting.
It works quite good, but when viewing the cube from a certain angle, its shows highlights with shouldn't be there.
I altered the shader so the specular highlights are red.
I just expected them to not be there because the light comes from the direction with the all bright cubes and there should be no reflections from this lightsource on the side of the cube.

Another thing which bothers me is, that there is an edge(Pic 2) where color changes. This is also something i don't quite understand and seek help with.

This is present when I use a directional lightsource and view the big cube from a certain angle.
OpenGl Version ist 3.3, i'm on Windows and using c++ with cmake to build.

Here are some images:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Github Link, because SOT does not allow me to upload code becaues "it is not formatted"(trying like 20 min to format them to SOT likes).

Edit: It works now, who could have thought that it was the formatting of the images and not actually the cpp, glsl code.

[Github](https://github.com/Redstonerayy/minecraft)

Important Files: light_proto.glsl, vertex.glsl, main.cpp

Files

main.cpp

```cpp
// RENDER LOOP
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    // INPUT
    //keysboard input, mouse input
    processInput(window);

    defaultShader.use();
    // CAMERA
    // model matrix set further down, dynamically for each object
    //view matrix, transform world space to camera space
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraPos + cameraFront, cameraUp);
    defaultShader.setMatrix4fv("view", view);

    //projection matrix, view space to device cordinates
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fov), 800.0f / 600.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    defaultShader.setMatrix4fv("projection", projection);

    // DRAWING
    //clear color and depth buffer
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    ////vertex data, shaders
    cube->use();
    defaultShader.setVec3("viewPos", cameraPos.x, cameraPos.y, cameraPos.z);
    
    defaultShader.setVec3("material.specular", 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    defaultShader.setFloat("material.shininess", 32.0f);
    
    defaultShader.setVec3("dirLight.direction", -1.0f, -0.0f, 0.0f);
    defaultShader.setVec3("dirLight.ambient",  0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
    defaultShader.setVec3("dirLight.diffuse",  0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f); // darken diffuse light a bit
    defaultShader.setVec3("dirLight.specular", 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);


    defaultShader.setVec3("pointLights[0].position", -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    defaultShader.setVec3("pointLights[0].ambient", 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
    defaultShader.setVec3("pointLights[0].diffuse", 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f); // darken diffuse light a bit
    defaultShader.setVec3("pointLights[0].specular", 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    defaultShader.setFloat("pointLights[0].constant", 1.0f);
    defaultShader.setFloat("pointLights[0].linear", 0.045f);
    defaultShader.setFloat("pointLights[0].quadratic", 0.0075f);

    //defaultShader.setVec3("lightColor", 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    //defaultShader.setVec3("lightPos", -1.0f, lighty, -1.0f);
    //defaultShader.setVec3("viewPos", cameraPos.x, cameraPos.y, cameraPos.z);

    //defaultShader.setVec3("material.specular", 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    //defaultShader.setFloat("material.shininess", 128.0f);

    //defaultShader.setVec3("light.direction", -10.0f, lighty, 10.0f);
    //defaultShader.setBool("light.isDirectional", false);
    //defaultShader.setVec3("light.ambient",  0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
    //defaultShader.setVec3("light.diffuse",  0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f); // darken diffuse light a bit
    //defaultShader.setVec3("light.specular", 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    //defaultShader.setFloat("light.constant", 1.0f);
    //defaultShader.setFloat("light.linear", 0.045f);
    //defaultShader.setFloat("light.quadratic", 0.0075f);


    int cubesize = 30;
    //draw cubes
    for (float i = 0.0f; i < cubesize; i++) {
        for (float j = 0.0f; j < cubesize; j++) {
            for (float k = 0.0f; k < cubesize; k++) {
                glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
                model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(i, j, k));
                defaultShader.setMatrix4fv("model", model);
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
            }
        }
    }


    //DRAW LIGHT

    light->use();
    lightshader.use();
    lightshader.setMatrix4fv("view", view);
    lightshader.setMatrix4fv("projection", projection);
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    lighty += 0.1f * deltaTime;
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0));
    lightshader.setMatrix4fv("model", model);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

    //GLFW updating the window
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Fragment Shader

```c
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoord;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;

struct DirLight {
    vec3 direction;
  
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};  
uniform DirLight dirLight;

vec3 CalcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir);

struct PointLight {    
    vec3 position;
    
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;  

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};  
#define NR_POINT_LIGHTS 1
uniform PointLight pointLights[NR_POINT_LIGHTS];

vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir);

struct Material {
    vec3 specular;
    float shininess;
}; 
  
uniform Material material;
uniform sampler2D texture0;
uniform vec3 viewPos;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    // properties
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);

    // phase 1: Directional lighting
    vec3 result = CalcDirLight(dirLight, norm, viewDir);
    // phase 2: Point lights
    for(int i = 0; i < NR_POINT_LIGHTS; i++)
        //result += CalcPointLight(pointLights[i], norm, FragPos, viewDir); 
    
    FragColor = texture2D(texture0, TexCoord) * vec4(result, 1.0);
}

vec3 CalcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(-light.direction);
    // diffuse shading
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    // combine results
    vec3 ambient  = light.ambient  * vec3(texture(texture0, TexCoord));
    vec3 diffuse  = light.diffuse  * diff * vec3(texture(texture0, TexCoord));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
} 

vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);
    // diffuse shading
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    // attenuation
    float distance    = length(light.position - fragPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.constant + light.linear * distance + 
                        light.quadratic * (distance * distance));    
    // combine results
    vec3 ambient  = light.ambient  * vec3(texture(texture0, TexCoord));
    vec3 diffuse  = light.diffuse  * diff * vec3(texture(texture0, TexCoord));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    ambient  *= attenuation;
    diffuse  *= attenuation;
    specular *= attenuation;
    return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
}
```

Vertex Shader

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 aNormal;

out vec2 TexCoord;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 FragPos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main(){
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);
    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
    Normal = aNormal;
};
```

Comment: I think the edge where color change is a texture mipmap/filtering problem. Try change texture filtering parameters. For the specular, I see nothing wrong in image1, but image3 is strange for sure. Which lighting computing is used for each image, direct or point ?

Comment: only directional lighting, i commented the point lighting out. you mean specular in the question or a typo in the program, because i didn't found one?

Comment: I mean the proper term is "specular" while you wrote "spectacular" several times. Did you tryed to invert (or to not invert) the light direction vector in your fragment shader ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have one issue and a half

First in image 2 (and 3) the reason why there is a line in the diamond texture is due to texture filtering. 
I checked your source code in Texture.cpp the Minification filter is set to GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST and you also generate the relative mipsmaps.
If you change

```cpp
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
```

to

```cpp
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

at line 23 of Texture.cpp and remove

```cpp
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

the line should disapper

I do not understand where the problem stands with the red specular light, if you could show the source of the light direction i think might be able to help

Comment: its a directional light, so the source is a direction vector set with `defaultShader.setVec3("dirLight.direction", -1.0f, -0.0f, 0.0f);` in the main.cpp file.
the light should illuminate every pixel which is on the already lit surface, but not the sides which are in line with the light Edit: setting the TexParameters solved the first issue. ty